# how to connect a python code to the server?

Tags: django-models

I have a function in my views.py that print a string. I have run the local server by django.
I wrote this code.The page of this project must show word "hello world" , but it doesn't!
Will you help me fix it?

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite.views import hello

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^hello/$', hello),
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
# url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: this is only the URL routes. We can't see any of your code that returns the `hello world` or the error message being produced.

Comment: This is my views.py content:                                                                                                                                    from django.http import HttpResponse

    def hello(request):
 return HttpResponse("hello world")

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I have error "404 Page not found"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by what you have and receiving 404 not found I presume you are just going to `localhost:8000`

However your url setup says that you should go to `localhost:8000/hello/` (you have no page set for the index pattern `url(r'^$', hello)` )

You also need to follow the correct syntax in your URLs. You currently have:

```
('^hello/$', hello),
```

You need to have:

```
url(r'^hello/$', hello),
```

You can also enable more verbose debugging by going to your `settings.py` file and setting `DEBUG = True`